# How numbers in string format are sorted?

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is list

```
a = ["100", "2", "33", "-10"]
```

when I apply sort like this

```
sorted(a)
```

It gets

```
['-10', '100', '2', '33']
```

My question is how it sort numbers in string format?

I don't need any code which convert string to integers.

Answer (score 0):

It sorts by the first character of them, so `100`'s first character is `1` so it is gonna be before `33` and `2`. Whereas the reason why `-10` is before `100` is because in the python character order `-` is before the numbers:

```
>>> ord('-')
45
>>> ord('1')
49
>>>
```